# Databricks SparkSQL job

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, google-cloud-dataproc

Does Databricks support submitting a SparkSQL job similar to Google Cloud Dataproc?

The Databricks Job API, doesn't seem to have an option for submitting a Spark SQL job.

Reference:
https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html
https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/reference/rest/v1beta2/projects.regions.jobs

Comment: what does it matter? you just do %sql <statement> ...

Comment: inside a notebook

Comment: So my use case is something like this. I have a multi-tenant Microservice which has to do some aggregations based on some changes to the data triggered by a tenant action. The aggregated data needs to be exposed via a REST API. The idea is to do the aggregations and be able to save them in my DB. With a DW like Google Big Query, we can get the result set back and store the data required in a synchronous call. I am looking for something similar

Comment: mmm. I'm not fan of micro services. in fact on my last assignment the chief architect stated, don't unless you have to. In any event I am not sure. I looked at the REST stuff some time ago, but I am more from the BI and batch / engineering side. Answer still holds for your question afaics.

Comment: did u find a solution otherwise?

Comment: Not yet with Spark

Comment: Not possible is the conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

No, you submit a notebook.

That notebook can be many things: python, spark script or with %sql Spark SQL.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this, can we run adhoc queries and get results via executing the notebook, we want to use like interactive livy spark session

Answer (score 0):

You can submit the spark job on databricks cluster just like the dataproc.
Run your spark job in scala context and create a jar for the same. Submitting spark-sql directly is not supported.
To create a job follow the official guide https://docs.databricks.com/jobs.html

Also, to trigger the job using REST API you can trigger the run-now request described https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html#runs-submit